# ExtJS: Excel-Style column functions

Tags: extjs, extjs4

As a simple example, suppose I want to make a grid of mathematical products:

```
A | B | C
----------
7 | 2 | 14
1 | 5 | 5
2 | 4 | 8
6 | 0 | 0
3 | 3 | 9
   ...
```

Suppose my database **only stores values for *A* and *B***. I then have 3 options:

1. Calculate *C* server-side, and use ExtJS models with *A*, *B*, *C* as fields
2. Calculate *C* client-side when initialing loading a record (via some reader?) **HOW TO DO THIS**
3. Calculate *C* client-side, after the grid has rendered, by going row-by-row, extracting *A* and *B* and setting the value of *C*
4. Just store *A*, *B*, *C* in the database

Thoughts? 
I don't know why, but I think (2) is the cleanest if I can find a way of doing it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 and 3 are both well supported.

For 3 you can use [**renderer**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) config on the column - lots and lots of examples out there.

For 2 you can map this right in the model as a calculated field via the convert function

Example from [**docs**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-convert):

```
function fullName(v, record){
    return record.data.last + ', ' + record.data.first;
}

function location(v, record){
    return !record.data.city ? '' : (record.data.city + ', ' + record.data.state);
}

Ext.define('Dude', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'fullname',  convert: fullName},
        {name: 'firstname', mapping: 'name.first'},
        {name: 'lastname',  mapping: 'name.last'},
        {name: 'city', defaultValue: 'homeless'},
        'state',
        {name: 'location',  convert: location}
    ]
});
```

Comment: I don't know why - but I never investigated the `convert` config for `Ext.data.Field`'s; probably should be called `calculate` or something.

Comment: What would you recommend?